# Punjabi/Telugu/Tamil on Android using unicode UTF-8

Tags: android, utf-8, localization, android-emulator

I am trying to display text in Indian regional languages on an Android app.
I've set up all the localization folders even though, I just want to have only one language for my app (say Punjabi).

In my strings.xml I have tried putting Hindi characters and Chinese characters and these are displayed correctly on the emulator. But when I put in Punjabi characters nothing shows up on the emulator. 
Any reason for this? Can I overcome this problem?

I have the option of using a .ttf file in the assets folder for punjabi font. But that is not what I want to do because it does not give me complete control over the contents being displayed. Each .ttf behaves differently.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for local Indian languages on Android as yet. Hence the UTF-8 characters that fall outside the acceptable range for Android are ignored. Hence we see a blank being displayed.